# What is the best way to include Mercurial changeset id (or revision) in a Django template?

Tags: django, mercurial

I am developing a Django site and am using hg for revision control. I would like to embed the changeset id to the footer of the site like Stackoverflow and Bitbucket do in their footer. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Do I have to use the Mercurial api? Is there a way to get hg form the CLI to output just the revision id so I can capture that in my deployment scripts and just include the simple text output in the template?

Methods you have used would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with `hg id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: [KeywordPlan](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordPlan)

In your release-to-production process, use `hg id` to get the current version information from Mercurial.  You can easily stash that in a file that you then include in your Django templates.

For example, in whatever script/process you use at release time, do:

```
hg id >templates/id.html
```

And then at the bottom in your main Django template (or wherever), add:

```
Revision:  {{ include "templates/id.html" }}
```

(NOTE:  the paths/directories may vary depending on how you have your template paths configured in Django).

Comment: Knew it was something simple. I looked through the command line args but didn't see id. Thanks

Comment: It's worth pointing out that what @payne suggests is exactly right, and that it's **not the KeywordPlan**.  The KeywordPlan page says why auto-expanded keywords in a DVCS are a terrible idea, and @payne's suggestion to do it externally is the right way.

Comment: This can also be used in compiled projects. It too much of a pain to use MSBuild configurations (batch scripts) to populate the version info, so I did it in an update hook. Much more simple, thanks.

Comment: It should be `{% include ... %}`, it's a tag. See  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include.